# Jenkins Join plugin with only a subset of the downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) to create jobs that should run only after multiple jobs have finished. However, when configuring a join task I can't seem to find a way to declare joins that should run after only **a subset** of the downstream jobs have finished.

Take for example the following pipeline:

[image: Sample pipeline]

`setup-deployment`is a join task that is run after all the tasks triggered by `build-core` have finished. Say I want to create a new task `build-artifacts` that only depends on the completion of tasks `sonar-app` and `cobertura-app` on the second column. Is this possible using the Join plugin or another similar one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve that with the [Jenkins Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin).

This plugin is really powerful if you have to design complex workflow.

Here is an example of one of my build flow:

```
// Format the build ID (long and short)
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
def now = new Date()
def short_date = now.format("yyyyMMdd")
def long_date = now.format("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")

// Launch the OpenDJ nightly build (try 3 times if random test failures)
ignore(UNSTABLE) {
    retry (3) {
        build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_build", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date)
    }
}

// Build the standard packages
parallel (
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_DEB", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) },
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_RPM", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) },
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_MSI", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) },
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_ZIP_OEM", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) }
)

// Build the DEB and RPM OEM packages (they depend on the previous builds)
parallel (
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_DEB_OEM", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) },
    { build("OpenDJ_-_nightly_-_RPM_OEM", BUILD_ID_SHORT: short_date, BUILD_ID_LONG: long_date) },
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the Build Flow Plugin doesn't get along with the Delivery Pipeline Plugin (which I'm using for visualization).

Comment: OK I didn't know these 2 plugins were not compatible :(